# 3D models for React App Dynamically Generated

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transforms, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I need to create a 3D box (transparent) and put inside of it another 3D shapes, such as cylinders and boxes. All of them need to be rendered dynamically based on data fetched from a Data Base. The 3D shapes inside need to respect the edges of the main box and their positions will be determinate by de data which cames from the DB. Any collision must be avoided and the 3D box must be allowed a rotation interaction to allow a visualization from different point of views.  When rotated, all the 3D shapes inside must obay the perspective of the main box and their initial positions.

In this perspective, I need help to identify: What is the best and light way to do this for a React application?

I tried CSS 3D Transforms. However, it is not easy to put all the 3D geometric shapes together without any collision or did not see problems when all the set of shapes are rotated. This is the link that I am following: https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/box, to give one idea of what I am searching.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: This is some of pictures of what I am trying to do with CSS 3D transform. However, the geometric coordinates is not organized to allow the identification of a pattern to generate the shapes automatically. Besides,the [position of inner shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TebW.jpg) is not good for all the points of view, as it possible to see in [bottom point of view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipOkL.jpg)

Comment: if the transparent box is used as the reference, any children will follow the parent rotation . have you tried anyting yet ?

Comment: Yes. I already used the same reference, and also different, but the shapes inside did not respect the position. For example, when you look the box from front, it is correct, when you rotate it to left or right, the shapes inside are in the same position. They just rotate in their own axis.